# Vim select the whole signed number under cursor ("iw" for numbers)

Tags: vim

Vim provides a nice way to work on text objects, eg. I can type `ciw` and I will be changing the whole word no matter where in it my cursor is actually positioned.

Is there something similar for signed numbers? Ie. both positive and negative? Positive numbers are a word anyway, so I can use `iw` but what if they start with a minus? Ideally I want to have something that can be later repeated (with `.`) on other numbers in the file, no matter if they are positive or negative.

Concrete example:
Change `-100` to `20`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`w` in Vim means "word", and "word" is a collection of letters from `:h 'iskeyword'` buffer local option. Hence an exact interpretation of `w` or `iw` depends on current option setting. There's no built-in "text objects" for every situation (although some plugins may provide them). There are only "word" and "WORD" (i.e. anything except spaces).

So your options are:

1. Use `ciW` if appropriate (number is surrounded by spaces)
2. Change `iskeyword` to include "minus" (it will influence many(!) other commands)
3. Find an existing plugin or write some custom stuff yourself using `:h Operator-pending-mode`
4. Use `:h ctrl-a`. E.g. `120 Ctrl-A` will turn "-100" to "20"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is kinda annoying that as option 4. proves Vim can recognize numbers on its own but there seems to be no way to use that recognition to select them.
WORD definitely might be useful, but not so much in programming, as typically a number is followed by a comma, or parentheses, etc.
I will look into writing somethings small that would recognize them in Operator-pending-mode, thanks.

Comment: @anula Care to share whatever solution you came up with?